# Android multiple database querys through webservice

Tags: android

First of all, the strategy that i have at the moment was achieved by searching here in stackoverflow, but by some reason, the "next step" was never mentioned here..

So i'm currently developing an android app that needs to fetch some data
from a remote database. I've searched in the web and at the moment i'm
able to get the data i want through a http request (rest webservice +
json response). My problem is, i can only fetch data of one database
query to my app in the same database session..

I wanted some strategy where i could send the http request, and them
perform 2 or 3 database querys and return them back to my app, without
the need to open 2 or 3 times a database connection, or sending one
http request for every query.

I know i can do some tricky manipulations with the json response, like
putting all the database query's response separated by some marks i
choose, but i was looking for some clean solution.

Can you help me achieve this pls?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you create some combined data structure which is the result of all the queries and then convert it to a JSON string, then your suggestion is the only other way to go, I feel. The combined data structure can then be recreated from the JSON received at the client end.

Comment: The only problem is that when i receive the json response, i'll have to parse it and retrieve some sort of a colection of my own objects. If i have combined results, and since i don't want to put this code directly on the presentation layer, i won't be able to return more than one collection.

Comment: If you're returning a JSON string then yes, you'll have to parse it. Your http request could be done via a service, then parsing into an object collection could be done in the service, not the presentation layer.

Comment: Are you refering to a android service? But even in that way i would have to send my collection to my presentation by some how. But i will have more than one collection to return.

Comment: If you want to do more than 1 database query in a single http call and return the results, then, yes, you will have to action them at some point, otherwise why do multiple queries at the database if your not going to use the results?

Comment: So, let me see if i understand everything you've said. I must do the http request in an android service, and have some kind of class that combines one or more collections of the objects i must return?

For example, if i get from 2 querys a list of cities and a list of users, my class will have two collections, one of cities and another of users? And then i would send that class to my presentation layer?

Comment: Yes. Of course you don't HAVE to do it in a service but if the query, data return and parsing are going to take more than 3 or 4 seconds, then you should do it in a service, otherwise you'll get the Application Not Responding error if you do it in the main activity thread.

Comment: Ok i got your point. It makes fully sense. I read that in android developers site too. But something that i read there too, was that it isn't advised to have lots of classes. Instead they say you should use inner classes instead of creating new ones. The thing is, if i'm going to create classes that agregate my combined querys, im going to have lots of classes..

Sorry for my persistence, but i like to clear my doubts in a exaustive way.

Comment: My opinion is that inner classes can be useful in activities where they inter-act with what's happening on screen or aren't used anywhere else. However, smaller seperate classes have their benefits and usually comply better with good design e.g. Single Responsibility Principle (SRP) and can be re-used.